# Vertically center text in a specific cell

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I want to vertically center the "Characteristic" heading in its respective cell?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs} %for top, middle and bottomline
\usepackage{multirow} %multi column and row spanning
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\subsection*{Results}


\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{} l c c @{}}
\toprule
Characteristic & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Result}\\
 \cmidrule{2-3}
 & Seaweed isolate & Coral isolate \\
 \midrule
Cell shape & Rod & Rod\\
Gram stain & $-$ & $-$\\
Oxidase & $+$ & $-$\\
Catalase & $+$ & $-$\\
MSA & Growth & No growth\\
Anaerobic & Growth (weak) & No growth\\
Motility & & \\
Indole production & & \\
Hugh \& Leifsons & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}


\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please learn to post *minimal* examples (and have your image actually match the code you post.) The code above doesn't compile (`\usepackage{graphicx}` is missing) plus it has many packages loaded that are *not* relevant to show the problem you are having.  People will be much more willing to help you if they don't have to wade through loads of irrelevant (and non-working) code.

Comment: All better.  I've added \usepackage{graphicx} and taken out the irrelevant packages now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it manually, using `\raisebox`, or you can use the `\multirow` command from the homonymous package (although, as egreg has mentioned in a comment, it's better not to shift the heading):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} %for top, middle and bottomline
\usepackage{multirow} %multi column and row spanning
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\subsection*{Results}

\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{} l c c @{}}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{Characteristic} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Result}\\
 \cmidrule{2-3}
 & Seaweed isolate & Coral isolate \\
 \midrule
Cell shape & Rod & Rod\\
Gram stain & $-$ & $-$\\
Oxidase & $+$ & $-$\\
Catalase & $+$ & $-$\\
MSA & Growth & No growth\\
Anaerobic & Growth (weak) & No growth\\
Motility & & \\
Indole production & & \\
Hugh \& Leifsons & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}


\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Or you don't. And it's better, in my opinion.

Comment: @egreg: I agree. It's better not to shift the heading.

Comment: You'll be pleased to hear, I settled on not shifting the heading after all.